# Using windows forms viewmodel in other class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, viewmodel

I try to read properties from ViewModel that is binded to some controls on windows form. I made ViewModel as singleton, so I'm sure there is only one instance of it. The problem is, when I go to other class and get singleton instance of ViewModel to read it's properties, they are not equal with these in ViewModel class. Here is ViewModel class:

```
class EditorToolboxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static EditorToolboxViewModel instance;

    public static EditorToolboxViewModel GetSingleton()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new EditorToolboxViewModel();

        return instance;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int BrushRadius {get; set;}
    public int BrushSensitivity {get; set;}
    public bool TerrainUp { get; set; }
    public bool TerrainDown { get; set; }
    public bool AddTerrainSlot { get; set; }
    public bool RemoveTerrainSlot { get; set; }
    public bool FlattenTerrain { get; set; }
    public float FlattenTerrainTarget { get; set; }

    private EditorToolboxViewModel()
    {
        BrushRadius = 10;
        BrushSensitivity = 1;
    }

}
```

And this is how I bind it to controls on windows form:

```
this.viewModel = EditorToolboxViewModel.GetSingleton();
this.trackBarBrushRadius.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", viewModel, "BrushRadius"));
this.trackBarTerrainBrushSensitivity.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", viewModel, "BrushSensitivity"));
this.radioButtonIncreaseHeight.DataBindings.Add("Checked", viewModel, "TerrainUp");
this.radioButtonDecreaseHeight.DataBindings.Add("Checked", viewModel, "TerrainDown");
this.radioButtonAddTerrainSlot.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", viewModel, "AddTerrainSlot"));
this.radioButtonRemoveTerrainSlot.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", viewModel, "RemoveTerrainSlot"));
this.radioButtonFlattenTerrain.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", viewModel, "FlattenTerrain"));
this.textBoxTerrainFlattenTarget.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", viewModel, "FlattenTerrainTarget"));
```

And now, when I click TerrainUp radio button and try to read value from viewmodel in other class, it remains false:

```
bool b = EditorToolboxViewModel.GetSingleton().TerrainUp;
```

In ViewModel class, everything is exactly as it should, but accessing it elsewhere causes data mismatch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that this ia a question about WinForms? Usually we have this design in WPF apps.

Comment: You can bind viewmodel to controls also in WindowsForms application.

Comment: Also I see that there is lack of new Binding keywords in radioButtonIncreaseHeight and radioButtonDecreaseHeight, but fixing it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if the objects are the same by doing a == comparison. Properties might have different values at different time because of the binding of one windows. If you confirm that the object is the same, you know that the Singleton is working and there's probably a binding changing the property values.

2) Singleton should have a private field, not an internal field.

3) Your Singleton is not thread safe so check that.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed my problem.

It looks like that's known bug, that radio buttons lost bindings during state change, so that's why viewmodel wasn't behaving correctly. Look here:
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/issue-with-radiobuttons-and-binding-for.html

One of possible solutions was to replace radio buttons with check boxes. But doing this, remember two things:

1. Set all checkbox bindings to false in viewmodel, then set true where it's supposed to be (if you want to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons).
2. **IMPORTANT:** ViewModel is being validated not when you click checkbox, but when checkbox **LOSES FOCUS**. So to force viewmodel validation after single click, just programmatically change focus to other control on the form, like this:

   ```
   void CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
       CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
       var otherCheckBoxName = typeof(EditorToolbox).GetRuntimeFields().Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(CheckBox) && !x.Name.Equals(c.Name)).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
       CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox)this.Controls.Find(otherCheckBoxName, true).FirstOrDefault();
       c2.Focus();
   }
   ```